# svn: svn: File 'CashFlower/AusgabenView.h' is out of date

Tags: svn, commit

I have the following svn error, and I don't know what it means and how to resolve the problem. Maybee somebody knows:

```
svn commit -m ""
Deleting       CashFlower/CashFlower/AusgabenView.h
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File 'CashFlower/AusgabenView.h' is out of date
svn: '/cashflower/!svn/wrk/be23ed68-704b-49bf-ac15-88f3164974d1/CashFlower/CashFlower/AusgabenView.h' path not found
```

Actually I do not understand anything. The file '/cashflower/!svn/wrk/be23ed68-704b-49bf-ac15-88f3164974d1/CashFlower/CashFlower/AusgabenView.h' does not exist and I do not know this path either.

Edit: Is is possible to commit a older revision such that it becomes the new latest reversion?

Comment: Try doing a `svn update` first.

Comment: Try an svn update:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87950/how-do-you-overcome-the-svn-out-of-date-error

Comment: Thanks: None of this helps I already googled the link you posted

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that *CashFlower/CashFlower/AusgabenView.h* has already been deleted in SVN repo (from someone else) and you are trying to commit deletion again. You can check that listing dir: **svn ls** . If so, then try **svn cleanup**, and then **svn update**.

> Is is possible to commit a older revision such that it becomes the new
>   latest reversion?

Yes, this is called [reverting to an older revision](http://www.sampablokuper.com/2009/03/27/svn-revert-to-revision/) (actually, what is described is not the only way to do this).

Comment: Thanks fro the answer: But svn revert gives an error
"svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided"
and "svn merge -r44:50" gives the error
"svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Merge source required." The hints provided in the document  don't work for me

Comment: You forgot the PATH argument (and that article presumed it is specified), take a look at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Comment: if you are in a root dir of version controlled sources - then use dot: "."