# Subversion set Bugtraq property failed - at least one property change failed repository is unchanged

Tags: svn, bugzilla

The subversion server is using apache2 in Ubuntu server 12.10
A very clean server without anything except necessary files for svn, apache, and apache auth
I tried to add a Bugtraq property for one of my subversion folder via TortoiseSVN client in windows 7
In the Bugtraq setting page, I typed url and message pattern only, others setting are remain default

The Bugtraq format are as following

```
URL: http://bugserveripaddress/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=%BUGID%

Message pattern: Bug : %BUGID%
```

The bug server is different from subversion server

However, it shows **at least one property change failed repository is unchanged** multiple times

Each time I clicked the OK button in error popup window, it will flash a small popup with *bugtraq:label, bugtraq:url, bugtraq:message*, etc

This looks like a hook script problem, so I edited my pre-revprop-change and tried to add permission for bugtraq:url, bugtraq:message like this

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
USER="$3"
PROPNAME="$4"
ACTION="$5"

exit 0
if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:log" ]; then exit 0; fi
if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:author" ]; then exit 0; fi
if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "bugtraq:label" ]; then exit 0; fi
if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "bugtraq:url" ]; then exit 0; fi
if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "bugtraq:message" ]; then exit 0; fi

echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log is prohibited" >&2
exit 1
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks a lot in advance~

Comment: Do you not get a sub-error after "**at least one property change failed repository is unchanged**"?  Have you tried creating one property at a time?  What about manually creating the bugtraq properties through the svn client?

Comment: The sub-error is "/subversionfolder/projectfolder/myfoldername" is out of date.
And yes, I did try to create property manually and it worked well. However, tortoise svn still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for jsumarall's sub-error question
I got a work around for tortoise SVN from the following link

[How do you overcome the svn 'out of date' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87950/how-do-you-overcome-the-svn-out-of-date-error)

check Michael's answer
Just update the folder then redo it in local side, then commit

pretty tricky...