# Can I tell SVN to ignore "commit failed; out of date" errors and force a commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Just now, I built a project in a Subversion working copy and tried to push the resulting DLL, myproject.dll, to the repository. I got this error from TortoiseSVN:

> Commit failed (details follow):
>   File '[path to myproject.dll]' is out of date
>   Item '[path to myproject.dll]' is out of date
>   You have to update your working copy first.

Okay, that makes sense. The version of myproject.dll which I have checked out is revision 9, and the most recent revision is revision 11. Subversion is asking me to update my DLL to revision 11 before committing.

Well, I don't want to. I don't care about the difference between revision 9 and revision 11; I just want *my* revision out there.

I do know one way to work around this:

- Copy myproject.dll to myproject2.dll.
- Update myproject.dll to revision 11 in order to make Subversion happy.
- Rename myproject2.dll back to myproject.dll, overwriting revision 11.

Is there a more convenient way to do this, or is my method the best option available?

I'm not afraid of using the command line, but I also have TortoiseSVN, in case that provides another way to do things.

(I've seen the answers to [How do you overcome the svn 'out of date' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87950/how-do-you-overcome-the-svn-out-of-date-error), but none of them seem to suggest a method that's easier than what I already have.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the answer you want to hear, but Subversion wasn't intended for binaries.  Your work-around is really the best way to do it.

Another solution is to go ahead with the `svn up`. You'll get a conflict.  Then use `svn resolve --accept mine-full conflicted_file.dll` and you'll over-write the repository version with whatever you did.  Just be careful that you don't overwrite your colleagues work.

```
$ svn update
Conflict discovered in 'foo.c'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: p
C    foo.c
Updated to revision 5.
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 1
$ svn resolve --accept mine-full foo.c
Resolved conflicted state of 'foo.c'
$
```